# App is stopping in some mobiles and in some it is working

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in AS. I make an app like status saver with the help of my friend. But it is not working and gives error App Keeps Stoping. But it runs very well in one mobile phone and giving error on other devices . When i use logcat it gives me this:

```
2021-05-31 02:29:53.423 26596-26596/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-05-31 02:29:53.425 26596-26596/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-05-31 02:29:53.469 26596-26596/? E/kTech.savestor: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-05-31 02:29:56.287 26596-26756/com.PakTech.savestory E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.leibniz.events.service.START on com.google.android.gms
2021-05-31 02:29:57.729 26596-26596/com.PakTech.savestory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.PakTech.savestory, PID: 26596
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.PakTech.savestory.fragment.WAPictureFragment.loadData(WAPictureFragment.java:65)
        at com.PakTech.savestory.fragment.WAPictureFragment.onCreateView(WAPictureFragment.java:53)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1013)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
2021-05-31 02:29:57.729 26596-26596/com.PakTech.savestory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2204)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9003)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:996)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:729)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

I does not whether there is a problem in gradle or in a code. As it is working in one mobile of new modle and does not working on reletively old ones. rom this Logcat file i am
This is very confusing or me. I am totaly unable to solve this error. As i said i am beginner and does not know why this error occurs.I really thankful if anyone solve my problem.

Comment: you are getting null pointer error. seems like you are trying to access an array which is empty. 
And also please check how to ask a question SO.

Comment: If you add your code, someone can help you out :)